# Why _id being an obstacle to find unique

Tags: mongodb

I was trying to answer [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65829706/filter-out-duplicate-arrays-and-return-the-unique-array-in-mongodb-aggregation)

I am seeing an insane behaviour where `_id` is stopping `setUnion`/`addToSet` find unique object.

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SL9ahxBsnrq)

[playground without _id](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9B0l8eIHBC7)

Sample element in one doc:

```
"newPMList": [
  {
    /**"_id": "5feb10c4906c880076ce5fa6",
    */"project": "5feb10b6906c880076ce5fa5",
    "market": "5feb0f44906c880076ce5f9d",
    "url": "https://www.example.com/place",
    "createdAt": "2020-12-29T11:19:32.945Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-12-29T11:19:32.945Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

It will be present as it is in another document.

Any suggestions please?

---

**EDIT:**

Out of curiosity, I tried the same in my local server.

My bad, When I try the same in my local mongo server, it works.

Playground is an obstacle in this case. I think it reprocesses the data before submitting to the mongo server by removing `_id` fields and generating new one.

But couldn't justify the same. I am happy to delete the question also if it doesn't make sense. please advise.

Comment: you could ask to mongoplayground.net [github issues](https://github.com/feliixx/mongoplayground/issues), since they are using `go lang` mongodb go driver api, you will get some hint how it works.